# Realtime MP3 Frequency Detection With Python

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

I was trying to find a way to detect mp3 frequency while its playing. Say for eg: I have a mp3 file and its started playing and it should show the current frequency. I am not sure how it can be done, wave files can do that. But for mp3 files I didnt find much info anywhere. If you guys can give me some help then that will be great.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "wave files can do that". Explain _how_ you would do it with wave files, ideally with sample code, and we can show you how to do it with MP3 files. If you're actually capturing the output (you say "while it's playing"), it will be identical whether the source is MP3 or WAV. If, on the other hand, you're parsing the file with the `wave` and `audioop` modules, then you will have to use a third-party library (`pymad`, `libavcodec`, whatever) to extract audio frames from the MP3, but after that it's identical to what you'd do with a WAV.